# Index a 2d array element

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL I have created the following package:

```
--! Custom, 8 bit register map package
package regmap_package is

    --! Amount of registers in the array
    constant reg_nr : natural := 8;

    --! The 8bit register map array type
    type regmap_t is array(0 to (reg_nr - 1)) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

end package regmap_package;
```

Using this package one has access to a new type `regmap_t`, which is a 2d array of size `reg_nr` x 8 bits.

In vhdl, I cannot figure out how can I access a single bit in this array. I was able to access only single "registers", that is 8 whole bits. I am trying to get something like this:

```
some_signal <= regmap_var(0,1);
```

In order to access the 2nd (bit number 1, counting from 0) from the 1st register (nr 0).

Comment: `type regmap_t is array(0 to reg_nr - 1, 7 downto 0) of std_logic;` would be a 2-dimensional array. You have a 1 dimensional array nested in another 1-dimensional array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a 2D array, it is only a 1D array, where the elements are themselves a 1D array. Therefore the you need to keep each index into its own ()

some_sl_signal <= regmap_var(0)(1);